# Wrong train/test split strategy

Tags: random-forest

The question is about a wrongly chosen strategy for **train/test splitting** in a RandomForest model. I know choosing the test set this way gives the wrong output but I would like to understand **why**.

(The model looks at previous days of data and tries to predict if next day's data will be higher or lower than today, i.e. a classification problem)

I copied the train/test split code from another example and it simply sets random rows to be either train_set or test_set. (Tried to illustrate below) 
[image]
Raw data is daily Close values of for example EURUSD.

I then create features based on that. Every feature looks at some previous data points and comes up with a set of features which is a row in X_test. I then train a random forest model to try to predict next day's close.

The accuracy in the test_set is very high and it increases with the increasing number of historical previous points it looks at which seems to suggest overfitting.

When I change train/test split model to have, for example, **train_set: data in January-June** and **test_set: data in August**, i.e. completely separate datasets and no possible mixing, the accuracy is a more realistic 50%.

Again, I know the train/test split it is not correct, but can someone help me understand why..?

My question is simple: Every time I want to validate a row (i.e. one prediction in test_set) I use features that looks at previous data trying to predict tomorrow's data? How come there is overfitting?

Comment: How are you doing validation on your training? ( [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-test-validation-datasets/) ) It looks like you only have training and test, for which I would expect very high levels of over-fitting with nearly any learner.